# AWS SWF ListOpenWorkflow

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am trying to retrieve a list of open SWF workflows in my domain. I am using the below code to retrieve the WorkflowInfos list.

```
 WorkflowExecutionInfos weInfos = swfClient.listOpenWorkflowExecutions(
                new ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest().withDomain(domainName)
                .withStartTimeFilter(new ExecutionTimeFilter().withOldestDate(new Date(2016,11,9)));
System.out.println("Number of Executions found: "+  weInfos.getExecutionInfos().size());
```

However the result returned back is 0. However on viewing the same on SWF Console page, I observe two on-going workflows with start times in the past hour.

Am I providing some incorrect information? Most likely its the `oldestDate` value. I  have however tried other variations for date value (e.g. 2016,11,1). However each the same result. I have confirmed the value of domain matches with that in SWF console.

Comment: Have you checked that you are hitting the correct datacenter? Also does it return anything without filter?

Comment: I, finally found the issue. It was indeed with the oldestDate value. Passing oldestDate parameter as `new Date(0)` worked. This suffices my condition. I will continue to investigate whats wrong with providing Date by passing the day,month,year parameters and update here accordingly.